# How to set up hidden imports in pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a large project with multiple packages. These packages use a set of modules in a common package. I am trying to create an exe on Windows using pyinstaller, but it cannot find the common package.

This cut down project exhibits the same issue. My package is organised as shown in this tree:

[image]

When I use

`python -m my_package`

in the top my_package directory it works perfectly.

The module main.py in my_package imports Bar (which is located in foo) from common. The __init__.py file in common includes:

`from common.source.foo import Bar`

When I build and exe file and run it in terminal, it fails with ' No module named common'

my pyintstaller spec includes:

`hiddenimports=['../', '../common/', '../common/common/']`

Should I try something different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hiddenimports` are used to specify imports that can't be detected by pyinstaller, not the paths to those imports.

Try adding the necessary paths to the `pathex` list in the spec file instead (these are paths that will be available in `sys.path` during analysis).

Comment: Thanks that helped. It works using absolute paths, I'll work on the relative paths shortly

Comment: ```pathex=['..\\..\\common']``` does it :)