# PyInstaller windows binary missing third party python module

Tags: python, pyinstaller

system specs:
PyInstaller: 5.6.2 
Python: 3.9.2
Windows-10-10.0.15063-SP0

I set up a virtual environment and install my requirements, check.
Following along with the pyinstaller [documentation](https://chrome-extension://efaidnbmnnnibpcajpcglclefindmkaj/https://readthedocs.org/projects/pyinstaller/downloads/pdf/stable/) section 2.6, I run the command:

```
pyinstaller myProgram.py
```

As the docs describe, this autogenerates a .spec file for my application.
pyinstaller generated spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['myProgram.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='myProgram',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='myProgram',
)
```

I have extra 'datas' that need to be packaged into the app, so I edit the .spec file as follows:
edited .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

datas = [
  ('galil/x64/libcrypto-3.dll', 'x64'),
  ('galil/x64/libssl-3.dll', 'x64'),
  ('galil/x64/gclib.dll', 'x64'),
  ('galil/x64/gclibo.dll', 'x64'),
  ('galil/x86/libcrypto-3.dll', 'x86'),
  ('galil/x86/libssl-3.dll', 'x86'),
  ('galil/x86/gclib.dll', 'x86'),
  ('galil/x86/gclibo.dll', 'x86'),
  ('galil/x64/libgclibo.so.0.0', 'x64'),
  ('galil/x64/libgclib.so.0.449', 'x64'),
  ('msvcp140.dll','.'),
  ('vcruntime140.dll','.'),
  ('vccorlib140.dll','.'),
  ('concrt140.dll','.'),
  ('vcomp140.dll','.'),
]

lib_dir = os.path.realpath('../../../../../../outputs/myProgram/update')
datas.append((os.path.join( lib_dir, './extraDataDir' ), './update/extraDataDir'))
datas.append((os.path.join( lib_dir, './manifest.txt' ), './'))

a = Analysis(
    ['myProgram.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=datas,
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='myProgram',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
        exe,
        a.binaries,
        a.zipfiles,
        a.datas,
        strip=False,
        upx=True,
        upx_exclude=[],
        name='myProgram',
)
```

Edits made, I go back and re-run pyinstaller on the spec file:

```
pyinstaller myProgram.spec
```

This completes successfully, and if I navigate to the output directory I can verify that the datas were added successfully to the myProgram application directory. However :(, when I double click the executable, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myProgram.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "myProgram_Controller.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "galil\galil_client.py", line 8, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gclib'
```

Ok, I assume this is because of the

```
import gclib
```

at the the top, and while I have included the libraries, I have not told pyinstaller about the actual gclib.py python module(?). Reading over section 2.12 of the docs, I create a hook file: hook-gclib.py:

```
from PyInstaller.hooks.hookutils import (collect_data_files, collect_submodules)

datas = [('./galil/gclib.py', 'gclib')]
hiddenimports = collect_submodules('gclib')
```

At this point start over; delete the pyinstaller output directory, backup myProgram.spec to .BAK, and re-run pyinstaller command like this:

```
pyinstaller --additional-hooks-dir=. --windowed myProgram.py
```

This generates a new spec file that I once again modify to add the required datas. The new spec file after adding the datas looks exactly the same as the previous with the exception that in the analysis block: `hookspath=['.'],`

Re-run pyinstaller on the spec file: `pyinstaller myProgram.spec`, double click the newly generated executable, & no dice, exact same ModuleNotFoundError  :(.

I do not get any errors for the hook file, but is it not correct, or?

Answer (score 0):

Ah ha! I was making this more complicated than it needed to be. no hook required. removed any mention of hookpath from spec file, and updated:

```
pathex=['./galil'],
```

I will leave this here. someone can mark it as a duplicate because I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56920912/how-to-set-up-hidden-imports-in-pyinstaller)